# How to subscribe to Blazor events from JS?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am creating Blazor WASM component that is used inside old Razor pages with some JS code.
Razor and JS should react to events from Blazor Component.
What is the best way to do that?
I have reference to Blazor's DotNetObjectReference in JS code, but looks like with that I can only call  JSInvokable methods from Blazor component but not subscribe to events (correct me if I am wrong)

EX:

Razor page:

```
<MyBlazorComponent></MyBlazorComponent>
<script>function thisShouldBeInvokedOnMyComponentChange() {}<script>
```

MyBlazorComponent:

```
<button @onclick="MyComponentChanged">
@code {
   public void MyComponentChanged(){
      //would be great if JS code outside Blazor can hear me
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you can directly.  You need to create a JS object with an event and a notify method, and call the notify method from your Blazor code.  What JS are you calling?  Can you do it in C# within Blazor?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis "Can you do it in C# within Blazor?" yes, but it is bad design. I need some eventing outside Blazor instead of managing everything inside it

Comment: just like you mentioned blazor can also call js, is it possible to change a design for your app? not triggering, but calling a js function directly.

Comment: @TinyWang it adds  high coupling and it's something that should be avoided

Comment: yes, but in my humble opinion, there's no build-in event for triggering js function...

Comment: @TinyWang looks like you are right, then I am looking for any other solution. Probably it's slightly better to trigger DOM events inside blazor component

Comment: yes, anyway, following official method could be good. I mean blazor provides option to call js, and let js call blazor method, at least this should be an option when we don't have any other better solutions.